# I'm confused with C libraries

Tags: c, linux, gnu, standard-library

Ok here's the thing.

Most people learn about the C standard library simultaneously as they first get in contact with the C language and I wasn't an exception either. But as I am studying linux now, I tend to get confused with C libraries. well first, I know that you get a nice old C standard lib as you install gcc on your linux distro as a static lib. After that, you get a new stable version of glibc pretty soon as you connect to the internet.

I started to look into glibc API and here's where I got messed up. glibc seems to support vast amount of lib basically starting from POSIX C Standard lib (which implements the standard C lib(including C99 as I know of)) to it's own extensions based on the POSIX standard C lib.

Does this mean that glibc actually modified or added functions in the POSIX C Standard lib? or even add whole new header set? Cause I see some functions that are not in the standard C lib but actually included in the standard C header (such as strnlen() in

Also referring to what I mentioned about a 'glibc making whole new header set', is because I'm starting to see some header files that seems pretty unique such as linux/blahblah.h or sys/syscalls.h <= (are these the libs that only glibc support?)

Next Ques is that I actually heard linux is built based on C language. Does this mean linux compiles itself with it's own gcc compiler???????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first question, glibc follows both standard C and POSIX, from [About glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/index.html)

> The GNU C Library is primarily designed to be a portable and high performance C library. It follows all relevant standards including ISO C11 and POSIX.1-2008. It is also internationalized and has one of the most complete internationalization interfaces known.

For the second question, yes, you can compile Linux using gcc. Even gcc itself can be compiled using gcc, it's called [bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29).

Answer (score 2):

Glibc implements the POSIX, ANSI and ISO C standards, and adds its own 'fluff', which it calls "glibc extensions". The reason that they are all "mixed together" is because they wrote the library as one package, there is no separate POSIX-only glibc.

`<linux/blah>` is not part of glibc. It is a set headers  written specifically for the operating system, by people outside of glibc, to give the programmer access to the Linux kernel API. It is "part" of the Linux kernel and is installed with it, and is used for kernel hacking. `<sys/blah>` is part of glibc, and is specific to Linux. It gives access to a fairly abstracted Linux system API.

As for your second question, yes. Linux is written in C, as it is (according to Linus) the only programming language for kernel and system programming. The way this is done is through a technique called bootstrapping, where a small compiler is built (usually manually in ASM) and builds the entire kernel or the entirety of GCC.

Comment: Technically speaking, glic doesn't **completely** implement the C standard, e.g, C99/C11. And saying gcc is written only in C is not correct either. It's now implemented using C++, see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commitdiff;h=2b15d2ba7eb3a25dfb15a7300f4ee7a141ee8539)

Comment: Yeah, you're right about both points. Edited to fit. I must have missed the news of the rewrite to C++.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more thing to be aware of: one of the purposes of the libc is to abstract from the actual system kernel. As such, the libc is the one part of your app that is kernel specific. If you had a different kernel with different syscalls, you would need to have a specially compiled libc. AFAIK, the libc is therefore usually linked as a shared library.

On linux, we usually have the glibc installed, because linux systems usually are GNU/Linux systems with a GNU toolchain on top of the linux kernel.

And yes, the glibc does expand the standards in certain spots: The `asprintf()` function for instance originated as a gnu-addition. It almost made it into the C11 standard subsequently, but until it becomes part of them, it's use will require a glibc-based system, or statically linking with the glibc.

By default, the glibc headers do not define these gnu additions. You can switch them on by defining the preprocessor macro `GNU_SOURCE` before including the appropriate headers, or by specifying `-std=gnu11` to the gcc call.